# 37,5-килограммовая штанга. Так употребляется числительное?

Tags: словообразование, числительные, дефис, сложные-слова, цифры

37,5-килограммовая штанга. Так употребляется числительное? Или лучше писать прописью? А если прописью, то будет тяжело для прочтения...

Answer (score 2):

Написание *37,5-килограммовый* соответствует правилу (см. [здесь](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=51#_ftn4)).

> Если элементу **-тысячный**, **-миллионный** или **-миллиардный** предшествует сочетание с *половиной*, то обычно используется цифровое обозначение с дефисным написанием... <...> Подобные написания иногда являются единственно возможными для сложных существительных и прилагательных данного типа... <...>

В том же правиле есть аналогичные примеры: *4,5-тысячный*, *7,5-летние* и пр.

В "Нацкорпусе" также встречается подобное написание, приведу лишь несколько примеров.

*Однако всё равно велика разница в размерах: **400-килограммовый** лось в 400 тысяч раз больше **4-граммовой** землеройки; птичка желтоголовый королёк меньше стрекозы-коромысла, а у орла-беркута размах крыльев более двух метров.* [Алексей Иванов. Message: Чусовая. Части 1-3 (2007)]

*А у нас в порту **20-килограммовый** брикет замороженного бескостного мяса стоит 20 долларов.* [Сергей Яськин. Крестьяне могут накормить Россию и Европу, убеждены аграрии // «Аргументы и факты», 2003]

*Но чтобы изготовить подобное копье, необходимо было размягчить **200-килограммовый** бивень, распрямить его.* [Т. Булавинцева. По следам легенд о мамонтах // «Техника - молодежи», 1971]

А прописью можно так, чтобы легче читалось: *штанга весом тридцать семь целых и пять десятых килограмма.*